# CSS select hierarchy segment

Tags: css

So I have an odd question. How do I make a selector that selects a segment of the hierarchy based on classes. for example i want something like

```
<node class="start-selection">
    <node>
        <node>content affected</node>
    </node>

    <node>
        <node>content affected</node>
    </node>

    <node class="end-selection">
        <node>
            <node>content not affected</node>
        </node>
    </node>

    <node>
        <node>content affected</node>
    </node>
</node>
```

I was thinking of something like this

```
.start-selection, .start-selection *:not(.end-selection, .end-selection *){
    /*styling...*/
}
```

but that doesn't seem to work because you cant have compound selectors in the :not() pseudo class. Is the only way that I can accomplish this to use JavaScript? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible do do with pure CSS, but a little script should do the trick

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll(".end-selection *");
for (i = 0; i < els.length; i++){
  els[i].className += " end-selection-child";
}
```

And CSS:

```
.start-selection *:not(.end-selection):not(.end-selection-child){
   background:blue;
}
```

Demo: https://codecanister.com/Project/d547eed9/3/result

Comment: Ahh i see. Thanks. This is kind of a bummer but I guess it's the best I can ask for at this point.

Answer (score 0):

It's really impossible to do using CSS only. 100%.